# Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ a normal extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I want to reason as to whether $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ is a normal extension over $\mathbb{Q}$. There are competing definitions and so my question is re-phrased as:

Is it true that for every irreducible polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ which has (at least) one root in $K$, $f$ splits completely in $K$?

Any help that can be offered is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is. A basic theorem in Galois theory says that a finite extension $E \supseteq F$ is normal and separable if and only if $E$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial $f(X) \in F[X]$.

It suffices to consider $f(X) = (X^2-2)(X^2-3)$. Its splitting field must contain $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$, and since $K$ is the smallest field containing both of them, $K$ must in fact be the splitting field of $f(X)$. Therefore $K$ is normal over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Many thanks, this reasoning I understand. I see my re-phrasing has been edited out; is it wrong?

Comment: The re-phrasing looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the polynomials $x^2 -2$ and $x^2-3$ in $Q[x].$ Yes, it is a normal extension.

Comment: The rephrasing is just the definition of normal extension.

Comment: Yes,you are right. I just forgot that $K= Q[\sqrt(2),\sqrt(3)]$. Oops!I better stop answering questions now. I have begun making some silly mistakes.

Comment: If you delete the part of the rephrasing this would be a valid answer.Well almost. The result to be used is that a finite extension is a normal extension if it is the splitting field of some polynomial

Comment: This also follows through from the definition of normal extension!

Answer (score -1):

If we consider $F=\mathbb{Q}[{2^{\frac{1}{3}}}]$, then $f=x^3-2$ has a root in $F$. However, the other two roots are complex. (Why?) But $F\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.
Hence $f$ cannot split over $F
$.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: @leo "Is it true that for every irreducible polynomial f∈Q[X] which has (at least) one root in K, f splits completely in K?" How does it not answer the question? It is a counterexample...

Comment: Read the question carefully not only that part. Look at the $K$ which is given